# Save-AzrWebApp func downloads a wrong SourcePath

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm using [Save-AzrWebApp](https://github.com/adbertram/Random-PowerShell-Work/blob/master/Azure/Save-AzrWebApp.ps1) function to downloads files from an Azure Web App.

How to do it is described here: https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-copy-files-from-an-azure-app-service-with-powershell

**My problem is:** it doesn't matter which `SourcePath` I set, it always downloads me files from `wwwroot` folder.

**Code example that I use:**

```
$syncParams = @{
    SourcePath = '\wwwroot\history'
    TargetPath = $TargetPath
    ComputerName = "https://$Name.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=$Name"
    Credential = $Credential

}
Sync-Website @syncParams
Get-Item -Path $TargetPath
```

Actually it doesn't matter what I put into `SourcePath` (even not existing path) it will download content of `wwwroot`.
How to use it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download file from web app, you could use this [web app kudu api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs) via powershell.

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$creds = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName joywebapp2/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

$apiUrl = "https://joywebapp2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/Content/Site.css"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo);"If-Match"="*"} -Method GET -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -OutFile "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\test.css"
```

Test result:

[image]

[image]

***Update***:

If you want to download a folder, you can use the [Zip api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip) in the doc I mentioned, it allows downloading folder as a zip file.

Sample command:

```
$creds = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName joywebapp2/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))

$apiUrl = "https://joywebapp2.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/Scripts/"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo);"If-Match"="*"} -Method GET -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -OutFile "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\Scripts.zip"
```

**Note**:The zip doesn't include the top folder itself. Make sure you include
the trailing slash, e.g,  I download the `Scripts` folder, we need to use `Scripts/` in the apiUrl.

Comment: I need to download a folder.

Comment: No, it's not what I asked for.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba It does not download the folder?